# How to move the first element of a list to the end of the list using Scheme?

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, append

I've been looking over this and I can add "something" to the end of the list, but the issue I'm arriving at is adding, specifically, the first element of a list to the end of that same list.

For example:

{1, 2, 3, 4} becomes {1, 2, 3, 4, 1}.

Here is the code that I'm having problems with:

```
(define (copy-first-to-end lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst)   
         (cons (first lst) empty)]       
        [else  (cons (first lst)    
               (copy-first-to-end (rest lst)))]))
```

The issue with this code is that, for the empty? condition, the answer calls (first lst) but because it is recursive, the first element of this list is empty. Since scheme is dynamically typed, I can't store the first element anywhere (at least I don't think I can).

How can I get this to work, using only the basic list functions? (e.g., cons, cons?, empty? first, last, rest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are essentially trying to write your own implementation of the **append** function, with the special case that you will be appending a list containing the first s-expression from the list.  Your problem is that you can't cons a flat list into a flat list and get a single flat list as a result.  The only way to do this with cons is to break the first list down into its constituent s-expressions and then cons them into the second list *in reverse order*.  Recursion should make this a simple task.

```
(define (append-first-to-end lst)
  (define (append-to-end a lst)
    (if (null? (cdr lst)) ???
      (cons ??? (append-to-end a ???))))
  (append-to-end (car lst) lst))
```

Between my example, Chris's example and my opening paragraph, you should be able to fill in the blanks.

I do hope the action required once you have the final s-expression from lst is obvious...

Comment: Remember that at each stage of recursion you want to be cons-ing a single s-expression into something else.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. For some reason I was trying to do it in a single  function, but having two functions makes it much easier. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use closures to store anything you want.

Here's the solution I wrote, with a few details removed to give you some space to think. :-)

```
(define (copy-first-to-end lst)
  (define top ???)
  (define (inner lst)
    (if (null? lst) ???
        (cons ??? (inner ???))))
  (inner ???))
```

In this case, `inner` is a closure that, among other things, has access to the `top` variable (which you will use to stash your value of interest).

Comment: Perhaps not, but note that you're passing `a` unchanged between each run of `append-to-end` in your solution. In such a case, I'd say that using a closure is indeed cleaner.

Comment: Thinking about it, since the call to append-to-end is in tail position, my solution is doing no extra work at all.  It's debatable which is cleaner.

Comment: Yes, it's a debate I've often had myself. For code snippets on SO, I tend to like the non-closure form, since it has fewer lines of code. But for my own code, I tend to like the closure form, since the inner function is shorter.